# compile undefined and unused function in c++

Tags: c++, compilation

Here is the sample code. I have a function `print` without definition and I used it in the `print_in_A()` in the struct `A`.

Why can this code compile and run?

```cpp
void print(int x);


struct A {
    void print_in_A() {
        print(1);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

And also, if I define an inline function like this, it can compile and run too. But if I remove the `inline` keyword, it fails to compile.

```cpp
void print(int x);

inline void print_int(int a) {
    print(a);
}


int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

[DEMO - Without error when inline is used](https://onlinegdb.com/QuKVwMYGV)

[DEMO - With error when inline is not used](https://onlinegdb.com/k5xncUumE)

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: One possibility is that you've set up a project that, in addition to the code you've shown, has a source file that defines the `print()` function.   Another possibility is that your implementation (compiler and library, possibly host system) supplies a non-standard (as in, not standard C++) function named `print()`  [possibly declared in some standard headers].   Try adding your own definition of `print()` to your source file and see what happens - if you get a linker error, that will be a sign that `print()` is defined somewhere else.

Comment: @Peter I've added two links that shows OP's error. [DEMO - Without error when inline is used](https://onlinegdb.com/QuKVwMYGV) and [DEMO - With error when inline is not used](https://onlinegdb.com/k5xncUumE).

Answer (score 2):

If the compiler can be sure that the functions using `print` are never used, it can remove them. In those cases, the linker will not complain since there will be no unresolved symbols. The non-`inline` `print_int` can't be removed since it may be used from another translation unit, hence, you get a linking error.

Comment: I've added two links(in the question) that shows OP's error. [DEMO - Without error when inline is used](https://onlinegdb.com/QuKVwMYGV) and [DEMO - With error when inline is not used](https://onlinegdb.com/k5xncUumE).

Comment: @JasonLiam Yes, the demos shows what I said in the answer. The non-`inline` version will cause a linking error since it can't be removed while the unused `inline` version may be removed and will then not cause a linking error.

Comment: @TedLyngmo， So why could the compiler remove the unused inline function? Does it happen in the compile stage or link stage?

Comment: @irasin It happens at the compilation stage. If there are no uses of the `inline` function, the compiler has no reason to put the code in the function anywhere. Later, when linking happens, there is therefore no call to `print` in the compiled code, so linking succeeds.

Comment: @TedLyngmo， So the conclusion is that any inline function, if not used in a translating unit, will not be compiled, right？ If so, what will happen when other translating units want to use the ignored inline function?

Comment: If the compiler decides to actually inline the `inline` function, and noone uses it, it will not have anywhere to put the assembly code. It'll still compile the function though, so you couldn't put syntactically invalid code in it. If _any_ translation unit is using the `inline` function, it's not ignored anymore and the compiler will put the compiled result where the function is used - and you're back to having a linking error.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, thanks a lot. I think this doc explains everything for me[ibm doc](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=specifier-linkage-inline-functions).